# Queuing requests to have just a single user "working"

Tags: java, web-applications, concurrency, queue, jms

Basically I'm trying to build a Java WebApp that will interface an Arduino. Due to this "phisical" limitation I will have just one user at the time working with the microcontroller.

I would like to create a queue with all the requests and set a limit (i.e. 20 seconds) and then go with the next user. There will be probably in the future the option to have two users connected to "interact" each other.

How can I implement this infrastructure? JMS? Other ways?

I've used other mqs as Kestrel but just with "strings", and I've no clue on how to use it in my case. : /

(I will probably use JBoss if this is relevant, or helpful)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is an RXTX Java library that comes with Arduno and I would suggest to use that for Arduno interface.

Comment: Thanks, I know the library and I've already implemented it for the pc-arduino connection. What I'm asking is about the integration with multiple users.

Comment: If you are alreadey integerated a PC with Arduino, then I would suggest to have a JMS Queue configured in the JBOSS and then inside the MDB(message driven bean), use the RXTX library for micro controller interface

Comment: Hm, ok. Could you provide me a wider explanation with the basic infrastructure editing your answer? I still have some doubts about it.

Comment: Can you brief about your infrastructure/architecture that you have ?

Comment: I'm starting from scratch so I'm quite free for now. I was thinking also about using a singleton keeping a list with all the requests but I don't know if this would be a good practice.. : /